# Sender account not recognized on private ethereum network

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm currently developing a dApp in Solidity and am working on a web3 library to handle communication with it.

I struggle with the process of new account creation and transaction signing in web3. Before I continue it worth noting that I'm running my own local, private blockchain (currently with Ganache).

My code looks as follows:

```
try{
    let a = web3.eth.accounts.create()
    let dataTx = someContract.methods.someMethod().encodeABI()
    let rawTx = {
        to: someContract._address,
        from: account.address,
        data: dataTx,
        gas: 10000000000
    }


    const transaction = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, util.toBuffer(account.privateKey))
    web3.eth.sendTransaction(rawTx).then(console.log)
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e)
}
```

The problem here is that the `web3.eth.sendTransaction()` method raises the following exception:

> Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized.

My understanding is that `web3.eth.accounts` is used for managing local accounts and `web3.eth.personal` is used to communicate with a client (e.g. Geth). I wish to keep the private keys of accounts my app creates locally on the device of the web3 client, but it raises this exception.

Where am I going wrong? Should I register the newly created accounts somewhere before running transactions with it? Is there some vital information I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an account other than Ganache provided you, you have to start Ganache providing your accounts data in the form `private_key,initial_balance`:

**Example command:** `ganache-cli --account 0xf38b5679751228eab7d9f3aa02bd0b0c0f7b44e448c0cfd410a1d7053efb6c56,123456789`

**And it's output:**

> Ganache CLI v6.1.8 (ganache-core: 2.2.1)
>
> Available Accounts
>   ================== (0) 0x44fa41e453654ccb365a358e994c764a37eea91f (~0 ETH)
>
> Private Keys
>   ================== (0) 0xf38b5679751228eab7d9f3aa02bd0b0c0f7b44e448c0cfd410a1d7053efb6c56
>
> Gas Price
>   ================== 20000000000
>
> Gas Limit
>   ================== 6721975
>
> Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to functionality in **web3 1.0.0** which is not yet fully released.
If you go to https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html
you would see that they state the following:

> This documentation is work in progress and web3.js 1.0 is not yet released! You can find the current documentation for web3 0.x.x at [github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API](http://This%20documentation%20is%20work%20in%20progress%20and%20web3.js%201.0%20is%20not%20yet%20released!%20You%20can%20find%20the%20current%20documentation%20for%20web3%200.x.x%20at%20github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API.).

Most probably you are using a version **0.20.x** or something like that so check this first. To check this open the dApp in the browser and type in the console the following:

```
web3.version.api
```

This should show you which version you are using.

I don't think there is a way to create accounts with web3js **0.20.x** directly but you can try to update the web3js to the **1.0.0-beta** and try to run your code again. You can find it in NPM here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue in my project. The problem in my case is beacuse i am not using same web3 provider to create contract variable.
example code:

```
const providerEth= new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    'HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545'
);
const web3Eth = new Web3(providerEth);
const contract= new web3Eth.eth.Contract(abi,address);
```

Here, we are not using metamask provider although both on same network Still it not recognize the account. So you should create contract like this

```
const web3Eth = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
const contract= new web3Eth.eth.Contract(abi,address);

const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
var receipt=await contract.methods.transfer(receiver,amount).send({from:accounts[0]});
```

Now, you can able to call smart contract function with account address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It happened when I already opened my truffle console and after that I did a restart of my ganache because I wanted to start clean.
**What fixed it for me was stopping the truffle console job and starting it again.**